# CANopen and CAN Driver

Tags: communication, protocol

**CAN Driver** means application program that interacts with CAN hardware and helps in initializing setup and communication.

**CANopen Stack** provides various APIs to deal with CAN communication.

Now this is confusing me so please let me know: **Is CANopen Stack and CAN driver one and the same?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not necessarily.

A 'stack' in this situation refers to a set of applications that are used for the overall product.  See wikipedia [solution stack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solution_stack) and [technology stack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Technology_stack).  The FOOstack would imply a set of software (the libraries necessary, maybe a specialized plugin or rework of the IDE (for example the SpringSource Tool Suite).  For example, the MEAN Stack uses Mongo, expressjs, angularjs, and node for a solution and thus bundle of software is often referred to as a stack.

You will sometimes see referred to the 'full stack developer' which someone who can work on any part of the system from client to database.

The driver is a particular piece of software to communicate with a particular piece of hardware.  Thats it.  A video driver is used by the operating system to communicate with the video hardware.

A driver may be included as part of the stack, but a driver is not the entirety of the solution stack.

Comment: In this case, the term 'stack' probably refers to a communication protocol stack, rather than a solution or application stack.

Answer (score 0):

The **CAN Bus** is based on the [ISO/OSI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSI_model) layers 1 (*physical*) and 2 (*data link*) and is standardized in ISO 11898.

The **CAN Driver** is a software module that interacts with the CAN controller and the CAN transceiver. It provides an interface to higher layers for:

- initializing the CAN Hardware
- sending *raw* CAN messages
- receiving *raw* CAN messages
- notifying the higher layers about received CAN messages
- controlling the operation mode (*normal, standby, goto sleep, ...*)
- ...

**CANopen** implements the [ISO/OSI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSI_model) layers 3 (*network*) to 7 (*application*). It includes the following features:

- transport layer, supports data segmentation/desegmentation, controls the sending and receiving of more than 8 data bytes
- network management, controls the state machines of the nodes (*pre-operational, operational, ...*)
- heartbeat protocol, used to monitor if a network node is *alive*
- SDO, PDO, SYNC, EMCY, ... and a lot more

The **CANopen Stack** implements the above mentioned features in software. It uses the interface provided by the **CAN Driver** to access the **CAN Bus**.

The basic CANopen communication is described in the [CiA 301](http://www.can-cia.org/index.php?id=specifications). This specifications is a good starting point for understanding the basics of CANopen.