# CAN Protocol Understanding

Tags: protocol

I have a task to convert CAN protocol Driver from Basic CAN to Full CAN. The project contains CANopen stack used in it. I have initiated the study of CANopen stack.

**I want to know is it necessary to study CANopen Stack and to how much depth should I study CANopen stack?**

Please note- Major task is to improve the drive code by converting it into Full CAN implementation

Comment: My understanding still now is- Full CAN implementation majorly deals wit Identifier section of CAN protocol, so COB-ID part of CANopen stack need to be studied. overview of all other section will be an add on value.

Comment: http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/a/6488/40980

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basic CAN and Full CAN are CAN controller types, so it is a hardware feature.

A **Full CAN** controller has several (e.g. 16) mailboxes. A mailbox can be configured as a receive- or a transmit buffer for CAN messages. Among others, a Full CAN controller is responsible for filtering of the received messages and for copying the content of the received messages into a predefined RAM section.

A **Basic CAN** controller has only one receive buffer. CAN message filtering, by periodically reading the receive buffer, has to be done by the host controller (CPU).
The host controller is also responsible for copying of the received messages into the RAM.

**Conclusion**

One of the advantages of the Full CAN concept is a lower CPU load.

It should not be necessary to study the CANopen Stack to re-implement or refactor a CAN protocol driver. As stated [here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/246383/128471), the CANopen Stack depends on the CAN protocol driver interface, but not the other way around.